# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptodomex'

Tags: python, python-packaging

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXX", line 7, in <module>
    from crypt import AESCipher
  File "XXX", line 3, in <module>
    from cryptodomex import Random
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptodomex'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my code:

```
from cryptodomex import Random
from cryptodomex.Cipher import AES
```

I have the cryptodomex package installed and are still getting this error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Check if you have different versions of python. If you have, then the package might have been installed in the file directory of the python version you are not using.

Comment: I am using Pycharm 2021.2.1 and have Python 3.8 installed

Answer (score 1):

The `pycryptodomex` pip package installs its modules under the `Cryptodome` namespace, without the x. Your imports should be:

```
from Cryptodome import Random
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
```

*(The `pycryptodome` (without the x) pip package installs its modules under `Crypto`, as a drop-in replacement for the old `pycrypto` library)*

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You should install `Cryptodome` library by following command line:

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

OR

```
sudo apt install python3-pycrytodome
```

You should try installing pycryptodomex rather pycryptodome(without x) using the following command line:

```
pip install pycrotodomex
```

As,

```
pip install pycrotodome
```

command gives **ModuleNotFoundError**

Comment: python3-pycrytodome -> python3-pycryptodome, pycrotodomex -> pycryptodomex, pycrotodome -> pycryptodome